# Getting a "Single" TRUE/FALSE instead of multiple in dice roll using sample ()

Tags: r

I need to write an expression to sample Five rolls of a single six-sided die, and output TRUE if at least one of them came up "1", and FALSE otherwise.

I tried the code below which of course gives multiple TRUE/FALSE but I need only single TRUE/FALSE if at least one of them came as "1"

```
x = sample(1:6,4, replace=TRUE)
x
[1] 4 4 5 1
x==4
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: You can do `any(x ==4)`

Comment: Also, if you read [`?any`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/any), it also suggests "see also `all`", a companion function to `any`. (Just an FYI, I know that's not the aggregation you were asking for.)

Comment: Thank you so much. any(x==1) worked.

Answer (score 3):

`any (x == 1)` will give you the desired output. Alternatively, `1 %in% x` will give you the same.